# Replace your changes in '/etc/ati/atiapfxx'

Tags: upgrade, dell, apport

I am facing a problem since few weeks with updating my Ubuntu.

Usually I receive a notice for updating my Ubuntu, I click download and install, it is be done smoothly.

A few weeks back Ubuntu offered me to update something not clear for me, which is the following:

`Replace your changes in '/etc/ati/atiapfxx' with a later version of the configuration file?`

But when I clicked on replace, nothing happened and the load process was stuck on asking me to wait.

I kept the laptop open for 2 days with internet connection but without any progress. I tried to attach a screen shot for this but it is forbidden because I don't have 10 reputation.

Kindly could anyone tell me what is happening. Thank you very much in advance.

Laptop specs:

intel core i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz*4

AMD Radeon HD 8600M series

OS = ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Dell Inspiron laptop

The laptop is working perfectly, but it is giving me error messages and keeps asking if I want to report it. If I say yes report, it will say this problem cannot be reported.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add there more information. What version of Ubuntu is installed? What do you mean by "updating"? Does laptop work OK now?

Comment: hello, i have edited my post. kindly recheck it. thank you for asking

Comment: There must be a checkbox not to report this issue again. Try to check it.

Comment: where i can find this checkbox?

Comment: When that error popps up.

Comment: yes i understand, but this checkbox is checked, there is no problem with the checkbox. any other suggestions. i wish if i could send you a screen shot

Comment: If you want to include a screenshot: upload it online and paste the URL into the question. Someone can then edit it and make it a picture.

Comment: hello colleagues, sorry for the delay in answering back and thank you very much for the people who concerned about my problem. i didn't do anything for the problem, after sometime i got several updates from ubuntu and it was solved automatically. but i have read over internet that it is a famous problem for all ubuntu's systems. anyway thank you very much for your support. i appreciate this a lot